# Default link color in python plotly sankey diagram

Tags: python, colors, plotly, sankey-diagram

The following code generates a simple sankey diagram:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go


label = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
source = [0, 0, 1, 1]
target = [2, 3, 2, 3]
value = [10, 15, 20, 25]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = label,
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = source,
      target = target,
      value = value
  ))])
fig.write_image("sankey.png")
```

For the links (which appear as grey), what are (or where can I find) the default RGBA (i.e. color + opacity) values? The reason I ask is that I want to leave the majority of links as the default, but change the color of a few links.

If it were a simple RGB, I would just use a color picker to find the color, but that won't give me the opacity.

Comment: that is a nice piece of code. But what do you mean "change the color of a few links" ?  do you want to change the color of the link that the cursor is hovering over ?

Comment: To check the default values for the colors of the Sankey diagram, you can use the functions provided for development. Try the following. `full_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development();print(full_fig)`

Comment: @r-beginners thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted. I would vote your comment, but I don't think I can

Comment: A response is required to vote, but I don't think this case needs to be answered. I hope you will vote for my other answers that you like.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the list of default colors in `plotly`'s sankey diagram, the line from the comments

```
full_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development();print(full_fig)
```

outputs the following node colors:

```
['rgba(0, 204, 150, 0.8)',
 'rgba(171, 99, 250, 0.8)',
 'rgba(182, 232, 128, 0.8)',
 'rgba(239, 85, 59, 0.8)',
 'rgba(25, 211, 243, 0.8)',
 'rgba(254, 203, 82, 0.8)',
 'rgba(255, 102, 146, 0.8)',
 'rgba(255, 151, 255, 0.8)',
 'rgba(255, 161, 90, 0.8)',
 'rgba(99, 110, 250, 0.8)']
```